# The resource cannot be found (Error in ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I've manually added a view in the Home folder called "Test.cshtml".

When I opened that view in the browser it shows me the error:
The resource cannot be found.

I tried the following solutions but still getting that error:

1- Right click on The Project Name > Properties > Specific Page > set it to: "Home/Test".

2- In RouteConfig class > RegisterRoutes method > Default MapRoute > set: controller = "Home", action = "Test".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add an `Action` called `Test` in your `Home` controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

`Visual Studio` can help you generating the view for the action, right click on the `Test` method and `Add View...`

You can read more about *Routing* and *Attribute Routing* in this [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) article.

Also a good read - [How URLs Are Matched to Routes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#how_urls_are_matched_to_routes)

Answer (score -1):

For my case, it's very strange. I change one action method in the controller to take in 2 parameters instead of 4 as was before but forgot to update the ajax call to the view and it caused this error.

Before: data: { officer: officer, "scid": scid, "timein": timein, "timeout": timeout } - causes error due to parameter mismatch

Now: data: { officer: officer, "scid": scid } - working fine now.